# How to write encrypted data on Scrapy (using Feed Export)?

Tags: encryption, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm quite new to Scrapy, started using a week ago, and I use the -o property in the command line to generate a file and I'd like that file to be encrypted. I believe I need to write a custom Feed Exporter (instead of Item Exporter, because I need to encrypt the whole file and not each item separately), but I honestly have no idea how. I'm kinda lost, I read the scrapy docs, but they are not very clear and detailed.

Note: I also use custom settings like 'FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS' that I'd like to keep working.

Comment: Why not just encrypt the file after it is created? What type of encryption? You might investigate using the `cryptography` package.

Comment: This program won't run on my machine and it will interact with other programs which I have no control of, I don't know where it will run, I only know that it can run scrapy, so it's better to keep all the program logic in a single program.

Comment: The type of encryption will be a problem for future me, right now I need first to understand how to make a custom exporter.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future trying to solve this problem, I created a custom pipeline. I instantiate an exporter in open_spider, and in close_spider I call exporter.finish_exporting() and when I access the file after the method all the scraped items are written in it. Before returning I read all the data from the file, truncate the file, encrypt the data and then write it again. Then I just close the file and pass.